# DeclareMathOperator with auto scaling parentheses

Tags: math-operators, brackets, scaling

Using the "physics" package, there's a nice behavior where if you write

```
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\[
\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The parentheses will automatically scale to account for the larger size of the fraction.  However, if I create a new command using \DeclareMathOperator

```
\usepackage{physics}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect}

\begin{documennt}

\[
\rect(\frac{x}{2})
\]
\[
\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This scaling doesn't occur for my newly defined math operator, but does for the arctan function.  I was wondering if there is a way to declare the math operator such that it matches the behavior of the arctan function's parentheses when using the physics package.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you load some package that makes the parentheses scale in the arctan example? That is not really common.

Comment: please show an example of the non standard arctan, then someone can show how to define similar functions

Comment: Apologies, I did not realize that it was due to a package.  Just checked, and found that it is being done with the "physics" package

Comment: In the [documentatin](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf), section 2, you probably find what you look for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OPs comment suggests a solution was found.

Comment: Instead of posting code snippets, please always try to show a minimal working example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. It would make things a lot clearer and therefore answers easier.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you're using `physics`. Don't, unless you deem the result of what follows typographically sound.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\[
\arctan(\frac{1}{2})+\arctan(\sup_{x\in X}x^2)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

It makes my eyes bleed.

If you still want to pursue this strategy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rect}{}{\trigbraces{\operatorname{rect}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\arctan(\frac{1}{2})+\arctan(\sup_{x\in X}x^2)
\]

\[
\rect(\frac{1}{2})+\rect(\sup_{x\in X}x^2)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Double eye bleeding.

If you want good typography, use autosizing parentheses with extra care.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parentheses}{(}{)}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\arctan}{}{\operatorname{arctan}\parentheses}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rect}{}{\operatorname{rect}\parentheses}

\begin{document}

\[
\arctan*{\frac{1}{2}}+\arctan[\Big]{\,\sup_{x\in X}x^2}
\]

\[
\rect*{\frac{1}{2}}+\rect[\Big]{\,\sup_{x\in X}x^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

See the documentation of `mathtools` for `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and note the thin space aimed at avoiding a symbol clash.

[image]

**Comment.** The package `physics` seems full of bell and whistles, but its syntax is complex and buggy. Its programming style is not what I'd call good and it uses several deprecated constructions.

Comment: My eyes are not bleeding at that. Visually, it’s not very different from your recommended solution. I’d probably only use `\big` for `\sup_{x\in X}`. Use `\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}` if you want truly horrible results. I’d use `\Big` for `\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}`, never anything bigger than that.